# Arithmetic with Factorials

Tags: arithmetic, factorial

The problem is the following (without using a calculator, reduce):

$$ {52! - 51!}\over{51! - 50!} $$

This is a simple problem, but I have not been able to find a good resource online explaining the intuition behind solving this.

My initial thoughts were to use something like:

$$ {52 \times 51 \times 50 \times 49 ... } \over {51 \times 50 \times 49 \times 48 ... } $$

and then cross out the common multiples to be left with something. It does not seem like simple arithmetic subtraction would get the right answer.

How do I go about solving this? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

Would some answer in the format of:

$ {(52)(52)} \over {49!} $

be on the right track?

Thanks.

Comment: Both terms in the numerator are divisible by $51!$ and both terms in the denominator are divisible by $50!$

Comment: So by this method we would be left with ${52! -1}\over{51!-1}$ ?

Comment: No, that's not right.  Check your arithmetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\frac{52! - 51!}{51! - 50!}
=
\frac{51!(52-1)}{50!(51-1)}
=
\frac{51(52-1)}{51-1}
= \cdots
$$

Comment: So just to clarify here - were are factoring out the largest factorial in the numerator? Factoring out 51! from 52! leaves us with 52?

Comment: @Ethan, we're factoring out the smallest factorial in both the numerator and the denominator.

Comment: I am not sure I am following - it looks like we factor out 51! from the top and then 50! from the bottom, not 50! from both the top and the bottom?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Factor out the least factorial both in the numerator and the denominator:
$$52!-51!=51!\,(52-1), \qquad  51!-50!= 50!\, (51-1).$$
Can you proceed?

Answer (score 1):

${51^2\cdot 50!\over 50 \cdot 50!}= {51^2\over 50} = {1\over 50}+52$

I'm not going to tell you how I got here, you'll have that part to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Divide top and bottom by $50!$ to get:

$\dfrac{52\cdot51-51}{51-1}=\dfrac{2652-51}{50}=\dfrac{2601}{50}=52.02$

Comment: $52\cdot 51-51$ is nothing else than $51^2$…